# How to remove the space between two sections in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem about loading 2 sections in Bootstrap and as you can see here in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/) there is a little white space between the page header and the top menu... So how to remove that so the both sections will stick together... Not that I also tried `margin-top:0; padding-top:0;` but they didn't work !

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what you mean, your problem is about navbar and gray square? If yes, just use `.navbar { margin-bottom: 0; }`. Remember to place it after you load Bootstrap's CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap `.navbar` has a default `margin-bottom` of `50px`. To remove that, add a new style which overrides it.

```
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```